# Existence of sequence of distributions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, probability-distributions, entropy

This question concerns distributions $\mu$ over the naturals $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$. For $q\ge1$, let us define the $q$th moment of entropy:
$$
H_q(\mu)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(i)|\log\mu(i)|^q,
$$
so $H_1(\mu)$ is just the usual entropy.

I am interested in a sequence of distributions $\mu_n$ satisfying the following properties:

1. $\mu_n(1)\to1$ as $n\to\infty$
2. $\limsup_{n\to\infty}H_2(\mu_n)<\infty$
3. $\liminf_{n\to\infty}H_1(\mu_n)>0$

Does such a sequence exist? I'd be satisfied with mere existence (though a construction would, of course, be nice).

If such a sequence does not exist (proof?), I'd be happy with the following weakening:

1'. $\mu_n(1)\to1$ at some *fixed* rate

2'. same as 2

3'. $H_1(\mu_n)\to0$ at an *arbitrarily slow* rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\mu_n(1)=1-t_n$, $\mu_n(2)=\cdots=\mu_n(n+1)=t_n/n$, and $\mu_n(n+2)=\mu_n(n+3)=\cdots=0$, where $t_n:=1/\ln n$ and $n\ge3$. Then $\mu_n(1)\to1$ and $H_1(\mu_n)\to1$. So, 1' and 2' hold; one may say 2' holds with an infinitely slow rate. It is easy to modify this example to have 2' hold with an arbitrarily slow rate.

---

After the editing of the question, the answer becomes no. Indeed, suppose that $\mu_n(1)=1-t_n$, where $t_n\downarrow0$, and suppose that $H_1(\mu_n)\to0$ so slowly that
$$H_1(\mu_n)\ge1\Big/\sqrt{\ln\frac1{t_n}}$$
eventually (i.e., for all large enough $n$).

Then $\mu_n(j)\le t_n$ for $j\ge2$ and therefore
$$\ln^2\frac1{\mu_n(j)}\ge\ln\frac1{t_n}\;\ln\frac1{\mu_n(j)},$$
whence eventually
$$\begin{aligned}
H_2(\mu_n)&\ge\sum_{j\ge2}\mu_n(j)\ln^2\frac1{\mu_n(j)} \\ 
&\ge\sum_{j\ge2}\mu_n(j)\ln\frac1{\mu_n(j)}\;
\ln\frac1{t_n} \\ 
&=\Big(H_1(\mu_n)-(1-t_n)\ln\frac1{1-t_n}\Big)\ln\frac1{t_n} \\ 
&\ge \Big(1\Big/\sqrt{\ln\frac1{t_n}}(1-o(1))\Big)\ln\frac1{t_n}\to\infty.
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus, whenever 1' and 3' hold, 2' cannot hold.

Comment: But what about $H_2(\mu_n)$?

Comment: Ah, I see -- my "weakening" was ambiguous. Fixed.

Comment: I now have reason to believe that even the "weakening" is impossible.

Comment: Thank you! I had concluded this from much more roundabout reasons -- but your argument is much slicker!

Comment: FWIW: my cumbersome, roundabout proof follows from Theorem D of Foster-Wyner: http://deanfoster.net/research/low_limits_entropy.pdf
(by contradiction: if a sequence satisfying either of my set of
conditions existed, it would be a counter-example to their result).